# Find and replace with asterisk character

Tags: xml, replace, find, notepad++

This is not really a programming question, I just have an XML file like this:

```
<product>
    <id>123</id>
</product>
<product>
    <id>245</id>
</product>
<product>
    <id>356</id>
</product>
```

I want to find all id's and replace them with just one "0". As ID's are different, I cannot use notepad++ because it can't find like `<id>*</id>` so how can I do it? The file is really long.

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool to process XML.

Comment: XPapth with `\\id` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML-aware tool to process XML. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) you can just write

```
open file.xml ;
for //product/id set text() 0 ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Answering as per the XML structure given.

Use Notepad++ Regular expression and replace \d+ with 0.

[image]

Comment: And what appen if you have: `<price>123</price>`?

Comment: Then use something like : Find  <id>\d+</id>  to <id>0</id> replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the tag content even in Notepad++ with a Regex-based find&replace:

Search:

```
<id>[^<>]+</id>
```

and replace it with:

```
<id>0</id>
```

This should be the find and replace window (remember to enable "Regular Expression"):

[image]

XML before replacing:

[image]

XML after replacing:

[image]